# Menu Assignment and Module Position Loading Error

Tags: joomla, menu, module, loading, administration

After customizing my site a bit, I am running into some loading errors with the menu assignments and module positions.  Here is a video with details:

http://youtu.be/MMrJbX_gkQQ

I am looking for some direction on what to google for this problem as I am unsure of the terminology of the issue.  Better yet, if you have experienced this type of problem before, please advise.  Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the video :D

The display issue appears to be a JavaScript issue. I'd start by first disabling any plugins that you've added to the site. If you are using Chrome, you can also right-click => Inspect Element => Console to see if any JavaScript errors are displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Well betweenbrain's comment was just the direction I needed.  I found that a custom jQuery plugin was causing the problem.  Thanks ;)